# Grouping summing and joining in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have spent hours figuring it out but couldn't.

I have a dataset `salaries` with following columns-

```
['yearID' 'teamID' 'lgID' 'playerID' 'salary']
```

It lists the salaries of each player of each team every year.

I have another dataset `teams` with following columns-

```
['yearID', 'teamID', 'W']
```

It list the wins (denoted by W) of each team every year.

Using these two datasets I want to have a datasets which have total salaries and wins for each team every year.

I have made many attempts and failed. Here's the one:

1. I grouped the `salaries` dataset by 'teamID' and 'yearID'.
2. I summed it to find total salary of a team at a given year.

   ```
   salariesGrouped = salaries.groupby(['teamID', 'yearID']).sum()
   ```
3. I tried merging it with the `teams` data-set but it failed because `salariesGrouped` only has one column, namely 'salary'.

   ```
   pd.merge(salariesGrouped, teams, on=['yearID', 'teamID'])
   ```

What should I do?

---

Sample Data:

Salaries:

```
yearID       teamID       lgID       playerID     salary
1999          A             X           ABC         100
1999          A             Y           XXX         900
2000          B             Z           YYY         300
2001          A             K           ZZZ         200
```

Teams:

```
yearID       teamID       W
1999           A          20
2000           B          30
2001           A          40
2002           D          10
```

Expected Output:

```
teamID      yearID       W      salary
A           1999         20      1000
            2000         40      200
B           2000         30      300
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try in this solution then:

```
Salaries = Salaries.groupby(['yearID','teamID']).sum()
Salaries = Salaries.reset_index()

data = pd.merge(df_salaries, df_teams, on=['yearID','teamID'])
```

Comment: It returns correct amount of total salary for each team but wrong number of wins. The wins belong to a team and should not add up.

Comment: can you show us a sample of your data and what the desired outcome would be?

Comment: Alright. I just updated the question with sample data and desired outcome.

Comment: It gives: `KeyError: 'yearID'`. This is because `Salaries` doesn't have a column 'yearID' and 'teamID'. I checked this by running `Salaries.columns.values` and it returned just one column 'salary'.

Comment: have you reset the index?

Comment: By the way what does resetting index does? Could you explain it in your answer. That would be helpful.

Comment: while you do group by the columns you group by for become index(if you group by multiple columns you'll have a multiple index). This is why you get key error 'yearID'. Simply because that column does not exist anymore, it has become the index. By resetting the index you can get back the columns and have the usual 0 to n index

Answer (score 0):

Will this work for you?

```
teams['Total Salaries'] = list(salariesGrouped.salary)
```

Comment: I don't think so because `teams` has 2745 rows whereas `salariesGrouped` has 828 rows.